# How to make select method in custom draw control?

Tags: c#, algorithm, colors

I am creating a control extend from pictureBox and only use GDI to paint the content. I want to make select method( Ctrl + A) to select content. How to do that??

Comment: Please be more clear. Are you asking how to capture Ctrl + A, or how to implement the logic of selecting content?

Answer (score 0):

I'd store my selection in a `Rect` (assuming you only want to use square selections).

When hitting Ctrl+A, you'd just do something like `selectionRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);`

Answer (score 0):

I want to change color of selected region to show that it's selected. My solution is changing each pixel colors of pictureBox, but it's very slow. I try using LockBits,it's good if Idon't calc color for each pixel. How to resolve the problem?